# JavaScript setTimeout and changes to system time cause problems

Tags: javascript, settimeout, system-clock

I've noticed that if I set the `setTimeout` for 1 minute in the future, and then change my system time to 5 minutes in the past, the `setTimeout` function will trigger in 6 minutes.

I did this is because I wanted to see what happens during a daylight savings change to the system clock.

My JavaScript webpage uses a `setTimeout` function to automatically refresh the page every 5 seconds, and if daylight savings were to occur, then the page information would freeze for an hour. Is there a workaround?

Edit: I am updating the page using Ajax, I dont want to refresh the entire page.

Comment: When a Daylight Saving Time change occurs, it is actually a timezone offset change, not a change to UTC. The test you performed does not model what actually happens if DST is handled automatically by the system. [Leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) might still pose a problem, however, as would an automatic time synchronization if the computer's clock had drifted far from the real time (so it would not gradually change the time).

Comment: I just tested this in IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, and Chrome on Windows 7 and I don't see the behavior you describe.  Maybe this is specific to the OS?

Comment: @idealmachine, is there a simple way to test for Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: @gilly3, I can reproduce this problem at will using the latest Google Chrome and Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: As it was said, DST is changing of a timezone offset. In order to test it, you just need to change your time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I will do is change from opening a new Ajax request every 5 seconds to using [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (long polling). It is a better option because the server will push the new results to the browser every time that they are needed, this can be every 5 seconds on server side or every time new information is available.

Even better would be to use web sockets and have Comet as fall back. This is easy to implement with [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) or [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

There are other options, like CometD or Ape.

Answer (score 4):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and your problems should be resolved :)

Update:

If you really cannot use either setTimeout or setInterval, you could try to have a hidden `iframe` that loads a simple HTML page that looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300"/>
        <script>
            document.domain='same as parent page';
            top.ajax_function_you_wish_to_trigger();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are lucky the meta refresh won't cause you the same problems.

Another solution would be to move the event firing to the server via [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). There are many reasons not to do this, not the least that you'd centralize the events and make them a burden on the server, but it could be considered a last resort.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve this problem. Same thing happens.

Comment: Unfortuantely setInterval is significantly worse.

Comment: Thats weird - what OS are you on? I cannot reproduce this problem with setInterval on win7 64bit in any browser.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered this problem too. In my case time change might cause serious financial loses so I had to take it seriously.

Some background:

- IE and Opera handles systems time change properly (no side effects to `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()`).
- FF < 4.0 and all Webkit based browser fails to handle changing time to the past (exactly as you described). Note: timers in Chrome however stops only after some time ~2-60s.

My solution: use some event from user interaction (i.e. `mousemove`, `mouseover`, etc) to trigger time change check.

```
Clock.prototype.checkLocalTime = function(){
  var diff = Date.now()- this.lastTimestamp;
  if ( diff < 0 || diff > 20000) { // if time shifted back or more than 20s to the future
    console.warn('System time changed! By ' + diff + 'ms' );
    this.restartTimer();
    this.getServerTime();
  }
  this.lastTimestamp = time;
}
```

As you can notice I restart timer and additionally synchronize time with server.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using [window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) gave me more accurate results and kept things consistent when the system time changes.

I used this as a way to get the current time inside a setInterval tick so that a countdown timer would not be affected by a system time change. I was calculating it based on number of ticks from a given time to attempt at preventing cheating on the timer (getting more time) by changing the system clock

```
getCurrentTime = () => {
  return window.performance ?
    performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now() : Date.now();
}

tick() {
  let now = this.getCurrentTime();

  if (this.calibrateTime) { //calibrate with a given server time
    now -= this.timeCalibration;
  }

  const elapsedSeconds = (now - this.startedAt) / 1000;

  if (elapsedSeconds > this.props.timeLimit + this.props.submitBuffer) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.props.onTimeUp();
  }

  let secondsRemaining = this.props.timeLimit - Math.floor(elapsedSeconds);
  if (secondsRemaining < 0) secondsRemaining = 0;

}

startTimer() {
  if (!this.startedAt) {
    this.startedAt = Date.now();
  }

  this.setState({ started: true }, () => {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 500);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the meta tag refresh to do this. This code would refresh the page every 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

As for the javascript question, it might just be the way the browser handles the setTimeout. It tells the browser to execute the code at a set time, and then when the clock changes, the code still executes at the time before the clocked changed? Just a guess, but I will have to keep that in mind next time I use setTimeout.

Edit: Ok, that would not work for ajax
Edit Again: This is a really good question. I am sure that setTimeout functions as I said above, but wow, this is a brain teaser.

Comment: I edited my question to add that I am using Ajax to update the page, and cannot refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fudge and do an `if (Date in range foo)` check. Basically check whether the current time stamp is within 5 seconds of daylight saving time and then just refresh the page immediately rather then by using `setTimeout`.

This way users get a minor annoyance near a known time change but the page won't freeze for an hour.